# c++ check cursor position

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, window, cursor

im trying to see if the cursor is inside my game not on the menue or the border inside the game. i don't konw what function should i use? i thought of using GetcursorPos() but is there better function?

Comment: yes..............................

Comment: @Bertrand - for reasons unknow, Microsoft use "cursor" for the mouse pointer. I forget what they use for the text-control cursor.@Ramiz - is there a reason why you can't just handle WM_MOUSEMOVE? Normally it only tells you about mouse moves within your window, but you can always SetCapture.

Comment: The text cursor is called the “caret”.

Comment: It is "caret".  Using the term "cursor" for the text entry position on a green-screen terminal is *so* seventies.  Lots of GUI users actually use the mouse that way, they click on the text box instead of pressing TAB.  Well, my mom does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetCursorPos() returns the mouse position.  ScreenToClient() is usually next.  That works for polling the mouse.

A more typical approach in a game loop is calling PeekMessage() inside the loop so you can see the WM_MOUSEMOVE message.  More efficient because you don't burn any time worrying about the mouse when the user isn't moving it.  Or using some class library to implement the game, mouse handling is always part of it.